# dynamically create table from external stage in snowflake

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, stage

1)Python to snowflake data connection is performed using python connector
2)External stage is set pointing to  S3 bucket
The requirement is to create a dynamic table based on each CSV.

Eg- I have 10 CSV present in the s3 bucket  then 10 different tables should get created dynamically referring to the external stage

Sql_query=?

Sql_query= copy into db.schema.table from @db.schema.external_stage (In scenario where table structure is  already created  in snowflake)

Comment: Nit sure this is even possible, but if it is you would need to write a stored procedure to determine the structure of each csv, dynamically create a table that matched that structure and then construct a COPY INTO statement to load that table

Answer (score 0):

[Refer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html) for python - snowflake connection.

[Refer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-cursor-fetch-values) for query data from snowflake using python.

Below Example will read a stage with two files and
create two tables based on file names in stage and
then insert data into each table.

This is how the stage looks [output truncated, column-wise] -

```
list @test_stage;
+------------------------------+------+
| name                         | size |
|------------------------------+------+
| test_stage/data_comma.csv.gz |  128 |
| test_stage/date_data.csv.gz  |  128 |
+------------------------------+------+
```

Python code to create dynamic tables and insert data from stage

```
import snowflake.connector

# Below setting up connection properties
# Providing all values for database, schema
# therefore prefixing those values later in code
# is not needed - can be modified as needed.

con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='user',
    password='password',
    account='ab313.us-east-2.aws',
    warehouse='COMPUTE_WH',
    database='TEST_DB',
    schema='PUBLIC'
)

try:
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    # Query stage and get file-names
    # Split file name to extract part NOT containing extensions
    
    cur.execute("select DISTINCT split_part(metadata$filename,'.',1) as col1, metadata$filename as col2 from @test_stage;")
    for (col1,col2) in cur:
        # Dynamic table creation is based on files in stage.
        # Here stage files are with skip-header, so column name are 
        # hard-coded.
        # Even if we try and get column-names from header row 
        # (if included) in stage file, data-types still needs 
        # hard-coding or perhaps fetching from other table 
        # if needed complete dynamism.
        cur.execute("create transient table "+col1+"(id number);")
        
        # Copy data into table created above from stage file
        cur.execute("copy into "+col1+" from (select $1 from @test_stage/"+col2+");")    
finally:
    con.close()
```

Comment: Can we also access unstructured data from S3 bucket and create dynamic table?

Comment: I don't think data is relevant in this case as unstructured data can just be copied over to VARIANT type column in a table. This use-case is more to show table creation based on files (file-name) in stage. If you have a particular issue related to unstructured data, its best to ask another question.